# Create multiple null containers in R (to be used in "for loop"), using a simple code

Tags: r

I'm creating empty null containers, to collect values from a "for loop".
Here is an example in my code, for which I've created 6 empty containers.

```
cont_min  <- NULL
cont_max  <- NULL
cont_unused <-  NULL
cont_n_rec  <- NULL
cont_n_don  <- NULL
cont_loop_time <- NULL
```

I need to create quite a few of these and it's using a lot of space using a line of code for each.
Is there a way to create multiple containers without having a separate line of code? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
names <- c('min', 'max', 'unused', 'n_rec', 'n_don', 'loop_time')
var_lst <- sapply(paste0('cont_', names), function(x) assign(x, NULL))
list2env(var_lst, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to do this in a single line, an option is `%<-%` from `zeallot`

```
library(zeallot)
 c(cont_min, cont_max, cont_unused, cont_n_rec, cont_n_don, cont_loop_time) %<-% 
    rep(list(NULL), 6)
```

-checking

```
> cont_min
NULL
```